# What is the use case of millisecondssinceepoch in flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime

I would like to ask what is advantage of using the milliSecondsSincEepoch over normal DateTime in flutter?
Could anyone explain? Thank you in advnce for the answer!

```
return {
    'createdAt': createdAt.milisecondsSinceEpoch,
    'updatedAt': updatedAt.milisecondsSinceEpoch,
    ...
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unix Epoch timestamps` uses a single, unique reference point in time (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00.000 UTC) and calculates the number of milliseconds elapsed since that date. Any time before that is shown in negative number of milliseconds. So the output is just a *numeric* output.

`DateTime` not only include the point in time but also information about the local time zone, daylight saving time, etc. The output is not *numeric* but a *datetime* object.

#### Why use Unix Epoch Timestamps?

- If you want to store and compare timestamps across different time zones, Unix timestamps may offer a more straightforward and consistent approach. It is also simpler to sort events or records *numerically* compared to sorting by *DateTime* which may require more complex comparison logic.
- Some say that transmitting data between systems or platforms using Unix simplifies the serialization process. APIs and data formats (like Json) handle *numerics* faster than custom datetime formats. I'm not sure how accurate this information is as DateTime objects can easily serialize and de-serialize using flutter's built-in Json serialization and other libraries.
- You can use Unix format as some sort of encryption so those who have access to your data cannot directly read or understand the entry.
- It depends on the compatibility of your database. Some databases (such as NoSQL) or those designed for distributed systems prefer storing numerics only (timestamps as Unix) rather than `DateTime` objects. The Unix timestamps would provide better compatibility and consistency across those certain platforms.

In flutter, you can convert DateTime to Unix like your code above:

```
int currentTimestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch; //Output: 1690437727035
```

and convert Unix timestamp back to DateTime object like this:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(currentTimestamp); //output 2023-07-27 16:02:07.035
```

##### My opinion

If your database or system does not require Unix Epoch, then do NOT use it.

Using DateTime objects is better for easy readability and understanding of what you are doing. Dart's `DateTime` widget provides a wide range of built-in methods for working with it and you can use libraries such has [timeago package](https://pub.dev/packages/timeago) or [Jiffy package](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy) to handle all the complex logics easily.

Answer (score -2):

The `millisecondsSinceEpoch` property is the number of milliseconds since the "Unix Epoch" 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (UTC).

This value is time zone independent.

This value is up to 8,640,000,000,000,000 milliseconds (100,000,000 days) since the Unix epoch. In other words: `millisecondsSinceEpoch.abs()` <= 8640000000000000.

Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/millisecondsSinceEpoch.html